# Similar pattern to promises/deferred's that support multiple results and cancellation

Tags: javascript, commonjs

Similar to the [promises pattern](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises) I'm looking for an event pattern that avoids needing to pollute objects with addEventListener/etc methods, I want to be able to return an object, that can be cancelled as well as 'resolved' multiple times.

For example, I may write a method that returns an 'interval' object, something like this:

```
var ticker = createTicker(1000);
var subscription = ticker.then(function() { console.log('tick') });
... later on ...
subscription.cancel();
```

The key differences here being, similar to a promise the events are standardized, so that I can subscribe without needing to know the event name, however unlike a promise, the "completion" can happen multiple times, and may even be cancelled (this would be equiv of removeEventListener).

I'm interested to see if this is legal with promises, such that the progress handler could be used for multiple callbacks, and the complete handler never used, but more importantly, that there is a concept of unsubscribing from a promise.

If this isn't the case, and promises are specialized to this scenario, is there a standardized pattern for doing what I described?

Comment: How about looking at the EventEmitter pattern ?

Comment: Personally I'm against the traditional patterns like EventEmitter, as this has a prototype dependency (ie- that all eventable objects implement event emitter members, or if you have a static EventEmitter then each library has to agree on there being just one EventEmitter), the promise pattern is good as it encapsulates the 'event' and doesn't require libraries to agree on a standard promise object, as the pattern of promises is all polymorphic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to cancel can be added to a promise implementation, without breaking the main paradigm of having single-fire success/failure callbacks.

In fact, jQuery already has cancellation for the promise instances that it returns from [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) calls:

> For backward compatibility with XMLHttpRequest, a jqXHR object will
>   expose the following properties and methods:
>
> - readyState
> - status
> - statusText
> - responseXML and/or responseText when the underlying request responded with xml and/or text, respectively
> - setRequestHeader(name, value) which departs from the standard by replacing the old value with the new one rather than concatenating the new value to the old one
> - getAllResponseHeaders()
> - getResponseHeader()
> - **abort()**

You could write a `setTimeout` wrapper that exposes a promise interface along with an additional cancel method.

However, once you get into the multi-fire territory, I think that is not what promises are intended for. You would have to define a lot of rules and exceptions around how multiple firing will play out alongside regular promise functionality. It doesn't make a lot of sense to me to use promises that way.

---

**Update (based on discussion in comments):**

Here's a sample implementation of a promise "proxy" that allows aborting further relaying of the done/fail callbacks:

http://jsfiddle.net/atesgoral/qvtqu/

Comment: Thanks, I agree that I cannot have multiple complete calls happening, any correct implementation of promise should error if the controlling code attempted to do this, so if a fake promise attempted to do this, it would cause immediate problems with other promises if chained together. Regarding cancellation I should have been more clear about this, it is cancellation of the subscription vs cancellation of the operation.. for example, an ajax call I would want to cancel my callback being fired, not the actual operation.

Comment: I guess more than anything I'm trying to find an existing pattern as I described, or if there is any discussion about unsubscribing callbacks from a promise.

Comment: You can write a proxy that relays the callbacks of a target promise. This proxy itself would expose a promise interface and can be cancellable. Upon cancellation, it would cease to relay the callbacks. Instead of writing your own proxy, you might also be able to use deferred.pipe(): http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/

Comment: I've updated my answer with a sample implementation for such "proxy". It can be extended to handle multiple promises.

Comment: Thanks Ates for taking the time to write that sample, I think ultimately I need a pattern slightly different to Promises in order for this to make sense (specifically around multiple results). Currently I'm using a simplified Observable pattern (translated from .NET IObservable<T>). But there isn't anything standardized similar to this in the JavaScript world.